# Deadlock using third party Ingear.Net .dll?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, deadlock

I am using a .dll from Ingeardrivers.com. I realize this question would more appropriately be asked on that site and have posted to there as well but more people on here makes my chances of it getting answered better.

I am a novice programmer and this is my first experience with threading. Basically I have two main loops in my program, and when I run each loop as the 'main thread' by itself - they both work fine individually. The problem is when I am starting two threads and running the main loop inside these threads, at some point in the loop they both are trying to use the Ingear.net dll and when one loop already has created an instance of the class, the second loop just sits on the constructor and doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: Could you check with the .dll vendor whether this library is thread-safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add-on is thread safe -

I was manually disconnecting the controller each time via 'controllername.disconnect()'
For some reason this didn't actually close the connection and I was maxed out on CIP connections. When I removed that, the controller somehow knew to disconnect by itself.

Strange but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend firstly that you check with the vendor to see if the library is thread safe.

But in the mean time you could try creating a single instance of the class and passing it to your two threads/loops as part of the constructor (or setting a property with it).

It'll most likely not work, but you won't know until you try.